# C# Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: 'Permission denied (password).'

Tags: c#, ssh

Its so strange and wired to me. The working code all of a sudden throwing exception without even changing anything in code. Please help me to understand why I am getting this kind of error? Why my working code is broken without changing anything.
Username, Password and IP address used are correct. I can connect to same IP with same password using putty or any other 3rd party tool but same is not working when I try to connect from my C# code.

```
           SshClient _client = new SshClient(ipaddress, username, password);
            _client.Connect();
            labelControl5.Text = "Connection: " + _client.IsConnected;
            if (_client.IsConnected)
            {
                stream = _client.CreateShellStream("sys rst", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
                StringBuilder answer = sendCommand("sys rst");
                MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection failed " + _client.IsConnected);
            }
```

Error Message:
[image]

I am new to this C# world and being stuck on this issue to figuring it out from last 2 weeks. Pls pls help.

Comment: Did u check and make sure server still allows access via password or If policy got changed to keys only?

Comment: Yes. I tried login to server with GUI, SSH using putty with same credentials. it working perfectly fine. Only thing I am suspecting is, For the first time login with putty, it will ask for accept ssh key, after that it will respond if the credentials are correct.

Comment: There may be nothing wrong with your code. You should check the ssh server logs on the remote host. It might be logging the reason that authentication is failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am using the authentication in calls using Renci.. perhaps the AuthenticationMethod would help you get going.

```
List<AuthenticationMethod> authMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
authMethods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password));

ConnectionInfo sshConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ipaddress, 22, username, authMethods.ToArray());

var sshClient = new SshClient(sshConnectionInfo);
sshClient.Connect();
```

Comment: still same. now I am facing session timeout issue. Issue is toggling between ```Permissin Denied (Password)``` or ```Session is timedout```.

Comment: Yes but still the same. I am thinking is there any way I can pass or say sshclient to accept key fingerprint always if there any changes. Can we do that?

Comment: did you manage to figure out a solution to this issue?